# Total and Average along with the Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

Please find the below input data. Need a query to show the sum in the output data. Output data is added below.

[image]

Output data should be something like below.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use DML+DDL to provide sample data, and formatted text for the rest. We also expect to see what you have tried.

Comment: [so] isn't a free coding service. What have you tried to get the results you are after? What is the logic to get from your existing data to the expected results? If you haven't tried, what did you research and what about said research didn't you understand?

Comment: Sure. I will follow the guidelines and also i will include what i have tried. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

```
select orderid, state
    , sum(saleprice) over() as total_sale_price
    , avg(saleprice) over() as avgsaleprice
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` and `AVG` as analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT
    [Order ID],
    State,
    [Sale Price],
    SUM([Sale Price]) OVER () AS [Total Sale Price],
    AVG([Sale Price]) OVER () AS [Average Sale Price]
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following:

```
SELECT A.Order_ID, A.State, A.Sales_Price, SQ.Sum_Total, SQ.AVG_Total
FROM YourTable AS A
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(Sales_Price) AS Sum_Total, AVG(Sales_Price) AS AVG_Total
    FROM YourTable
) SQ
```